# Is there a way to increase the carrying limit?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm constantly at the limit of weight Geralt can carry around due to all the crafting and alchemical ingredients I'm carrying around. My large collection of assorted monster parts in my inventory gets very heavy sometimes.

Is there any way to significantly increase the weight limit, so I don't have to run back and sell stuff so often?

Comment: @Raven Thinking about it, [gameplay] as a tag is *pretty* broad and overreaching, so I don't really think of it as a good tag. [I might suggest this meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/gameplay-and-general-gaming-tags) if you want to support its existence, but it's otherwise a bit *too* applicable for this site, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Strong Back achievement is based on whether or not you killed Aryan La Valette. If you let him live and then meet up with him in the dungeon you get the ability. If you kill him, you miss out.

There is also a mod floating around the net that makes all items weigh nothing if that is to your fancy.

Comment: Any mods to make things sort more sensibly?

Answer (score 4):

The "Strong Back" ability grants an additional 50 carrying capacity. It is gained by picking up a large amount of loot in the La Vallette dungeon in the prologue. However, there are reports that some people get the ability and others don't, so it may be buggy, or you may just have to collect every single scrap of loot.

Additionally, some pieces of armor can increase your maximum load.

Comment: You obtain this ability by spare Aryan de La Vallette at the top of his tower and help him to escape.